# Python -How to Automate Browser Prompts?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to automate the work mentioned below:
I want to click that button without my physical I want to automate it but I Don't need selenium to handle it cuz I tried it earlier and it didn't work so, is there is any way other than selenium ???

[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mn5VH.png)

I want to click that "Open Cisco Webex Meeting" Button

Comment: It should work with selenium, you have to switch to the alert, for an example check [this](https://www.guru99.com/alert-popup-handling-selenium.html) site. Next to using selenium I do not know if there is a way to interact with java script pop-ups.

Comment: @Thymen i have tried to use that switchto function of selenium then also it gave me a error selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: Message: no such alert      
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88) so it doesnt work

Comment: Ok, possible alternative, did you try using the tab key, or enter key? Because usually those pop-ups are automatically focused on.

Comment: yeah but i was trying for headless mode of selenium so should i  also able to use that tab and enter key?

Comment: I never tried that, but I can't think of a reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: ok i will try it

Comment: Any reason of tagging it with selenium tags when you don't want to use Selenium ??

Answer (score 2):

This Works for me

```
from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys

#open your meeting link 
#after opening meeting link you can give

send_keys("{LEFT}")
send_keys("{ENTER}")

#this will select the "open cisco Webex meeting" option
```

for example:

```
import webbrowser
from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys

webbrowser.open("meeting_link") #place your meeting link 
time.sleep(5) #my browser is slow so added sleep till page get loaded
send_keys("{LEFT}")
send_keys("{ENTER}")
```